# Integracion WebService REST a proyecto WEB

Tags: webservice, rest

Buenas tardes!

Mi problema es el siguiente: al intentar integrar un webService a aplicación WEB lanza el siguiente error:

```js
    12-Oct-2017 13:59:01.214 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Excepción de reserva de espacio para servlet mx.com.papelera.restjson.RestJsonApplication
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2494)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:860)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
 at mx.com.papelera.restjson.RestJsonApplication.<init>(RestJsonApplication.java:19)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:192)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:179)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory._getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:159)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:153)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig$ApplicationHolder.<init>(DeferredResourceConfig.java:84)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig$ApplicationHolder.<init>(DeferredResourceConfig.java:78)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig.getApplication(DeferredResourceConfig.java:75)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1140)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:837)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

No se a que se deba, se esta usando Hibernate,Spring, Struts.

Asi declaro mi webService

```js
 @ApplicationPath("/rest/")
public class RestJsonApplication extends PackagesResourceConfig {

    public RestJsonApplication() {
        super("com.mx.kensei.restjson.v1.resources.impl");
    }
}
```